# bash resize text grid

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a bash script to do some text processing on a file. Part of the file includes a grid of values that must be reformatted so it has the correct amount of columns.

Here's an example of the grid, which in this case must be formatted into 16 columns;

```
   702.0   697.0   687.0   685.0   693.0   700.0   693.0   681.0   676.0   684.0
   694.0   700.0   704.0   710.0   710.0   710.0
   711.0   704.0   697.0   690.0   693.0   699.5   696.0   692.0   680.0   687.0
   696.0   705.0   709.0   714.0   716.0   714.0
   722.0   711.0   708.0   700.0   696.0   703.0   701.0   692.0   678.0   684.0
   695.0   707.0   712.0   713.0   716.0   717.0
   727.0   718.0   712.0   707.0   705.0   706.5   701.0   692.0   680.0   683.0
   693.0   706.0   714.0   718.0   720.0   718.0
   732.0   728.0   725.0   718.0   715.0   708.0   699.0   693.0   683.0   681.0
   694.0   703.0   711.0   715.0   723.0   727.0
   738.0   735.0   732.0   721.0   723.0   712.0   702.0   696.0   690.0   681.0
   693.0   701.0   709.0   712.0   720.0   726.0
   736.5   736.5   734.0   728.0   726.5   718.8   714.5   707.5   701.0   687.0
   684.5   695.5   703.0   708.0   716.0   721.5
   736.0   734.0   727.0   726.0   723.0   720.0   723.0   713.0   708.0   699.0
   678.0   686.0   696.0   706.0   712.0   714.0
   729.0   726.0   717.0   716.0   715.0   717.0   720.0   714.0   710.0   700.0
   678.0   679.0   689.0   700.0   702.0   708.0
   722.0   719.0   713.0   709.0   705.0   711.0   719.0   716.0   706.0   697.0
   680.0   679.0   682.0   694.0   698.0   702.0
   712.0   713.0   707.0   704.0   697.0   708.5   719.0   715.0   705.0   693.0
   678.0   680.0   682.0   683.0   685.0   691.0
   707.0   706.0   702.0   693.0   699.0   710.5   712.0   707.0   701.0   687.0
   677.0   687.0   686.0   686.0   680.0   682.0
```

This is my script thus far, which fails to do as intended;

```
#!/bin/bash

Target=${1:-"grid.dat"}
Outfile="grid.new.dat"
ColumnCount="16"

RawGrid=()
while read line; do
    RawGrid+=($line)
done < <(cat ${Target} )
echo "${#RawGrid[@]} cells found!"

echo "" > ${Outfile}
for (( i=0; i < ${#RawGrid[@]}; i+=1 )); do
    echo -n "   ${RawGrid[$i]}" >> $Outfile
    ((i % ${ColumnCount} == 0)) && (( i > 0 )) && echo "" >> $Outfile # New row
done
```

The part I'm particularly stuck with is printing the grid with the correct number of columns. Perhaps I'm not populating the array correctly?

Comment: try `grep -o '[0-9.]\+' ip.txt | pr -16ats`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the number of columns is greater than 20~. It also removes the spacing before each column, which must be retained.

Comment: spacing is lost, agreed.. but this should work regardless of number of columns

Comment: and if number of spaces between columns is a constant known value, you can pass that as argument to `-s` option.. for ex: `pr -16ats'  '` for two spaces between columns

Comment: The error I get when there's too many columns is "pr: page width too narrow", in which case I was using 33 columns.

Comment: you are right, beyond 24, I too get the error `pr: page width too narrow`.. not sure if there is a workaround

Comment: can you try `grep -o '[0-9.]\+' ip.txt | paste -d' ' $(printf -- "- %.s" {1..33}) | sed 's/ /  /g'` where the `sed` command will replace single space with required number of spaces

Comment: That did the trick. Though when replacing the hardcoded "33" with my variable `${DimensionsArr[0]}` it fails to produce the grid as expected.

Comment: actually I found a workaround with `pr`... try `grep -o '[0-9.]\+' ip.txt | pr -J -w 2500 -33ats' '` (add another zero to `-w` value if needed)... so now you can use variable for that.. `pr -J -w 2500 -"${DimensionsArr[0]}"ats' '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd tackle this problem;

```
#!/bin/bash

unset IFS  # reset internal field separator

Target=${1:-"grid.dat"}
Outfile="grid.new.dat"
ColumnCount="16"
Separator=" "

Counter=0  # total cell count
while read line; do
    # Default IFS is space, so this "just works"
    for field in $line; do
        Counter=$((Counter+1))
        printf "$field" >> $Outfile
        # If counter is divisible by 16, insert a new line. Otherwise, insert
        # separator
        if [ $((Counter%ColumnCount)) -eq 0 ]; then
            printf "\n" >> $Outfile
        else
            printf "$Separator" >> $Outfile
        fi
    done
done < ${Target}  # no need for cat here
echo "${Counter} cells found!"
```

This is a little slower on my MBP than the speed of the script in your question with the original dataset-

```
$ command time -l ./original.sh
192 cells found!
        0.03 real         0.01 user         0.00 sys
   2596864  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
      1815  page reclaims
         0  page faults
         0  swaps
         0  block input operations
         3  block output operations
         0  messages sent
         0  messages received
         1  signals received
         2  voluntary context switches
       126  involuntary context switches

$ command time -l ./new.sh
192 cells found!
        0.04 real         0.01 user         0.01 sys
   2555904  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
       644  page reclaims
         0  page faults
         0  swaps
         0  block input operations
         1  block output operations
         0  messages sent
         0  messages received
         0  signals received
         0  voluntary context switches
       333  involuntary context switche
```

However, since it only stores the latest row + current field + counter in memory, it can now handle an infinite number of rows. Let's try a larger dataset...

```
$ for i in {1..1000}; do cat grid.dat >> monster-grid.dat; done
$ command time -l ./new.sh monster-grid.dat
192000 cells found!
       28.88 real        11.38 user        10.02 sys
   2936832  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
       737  page reclaims
         0  page faults
         0  swaps
         0  block input operations
         5  block output operations
         0  messages sent
         0  messages received
         0  signals received
         2  voluntary context switches
    356677  involuntary context switches

$ command time -l ./original.sh monster-grid.dat
192000 cells found!
      266.32 real       222.08 user        13.82 sys
  12320768  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
      4222  page reclaims
         0  page faults
         0  swaps
         0  block input operations
        23  block output operations
         0  messages sent
         0  messages received
         1  signals received
    179607  voluntary context switches
    295379  involuntary context switches
```

We can see now that performance is quite poor in both cases, but the new one does indeed save some memory, and is now actually faster with the larger result set than the original script. But yeah, as @Sundeep suggests, [pr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pr) is *by far* the best answer-

```
$ command time -l grep -o '[0-9.]\+' monster-grid.dat | pr -16ats > grid.new.dat
        0.17 real         0.17 user         0.00 sys
   2220032  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
       562  page reclaims
         0  page faults
         0  swaps
         0  block input operations
         0  block output operations
         0  messages sent
         0  messages received
         0  signals received
         0  voluntary context switches
       198  involuntary context switches
```